# Java, get panel landed on mouse event

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, jpanel

I have a draggable panel (not using the java drag and drop) that has to land on another panel. The dragged panel generates the event but I want to obtain the panel it lands on. Do I have to have an array of all the "landable" panels somewhere and cycle through it to get the one I want by comparing positions or is there a faster, better way? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `Container` class has a `findComponentAt(...)` method.